# KineticJS and requestanimationframe

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, kineticjs

I really like the KineticJS framework and would like to use it for a canvas game I am creating.

However, all information about animation and redrawing with KinecticJS I can find seems to be event driven, which would not work for me as I need to be able to redraw every layer on each frame preferably with requestanimationframe.

Is there any information on KineticJS working with requestanimationframe?

Also would something like the following work without hampering performance?

```
function main ()
        update();
        stage.clear();
        stage.addLayer(backgroundLayer);
        stage.addLayer(playerLayer); 
        stage.addLayer(foregroundLayer);
        requestAnimationFrame(main);
      }
main();
```

Answer (score 0):

As a user of KineticJS I think EaselJS may better suit your needs...

Check out their animation APIs:
http://www.createjs.com/tutorials/Animation%20and%20Ticker/